# I was wondering if I have the right data type for these databases I have to create

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

The commission classification column should be able to store integers up to a maximum value of 99 and be named comm_id. The value of the Comm_id column should be set to a value of 10 automatically if no value is provided when a row is added. The benefits code column should also accommodate integer values up to a maximum of 99 and be named ben_id.

A new table, commrate, must be created to store the commission rate schedule and must contain the following columns:

comm_id: a numberic column similar to the one added to the ACCTMANAGER table

Comm_rank: A character field that can store a tank name allowing up to 15 characters

Rate: a numeric field that can store two decimal digits (such as .01 or .03

a new table, benefits, must be created to store the available benefit plan options and must contain the following columns:

ben_id: a numberic column similar to the one added to the acctmanager table

ben_plan: a character field that can store a single character value

ben_provider: a numberic field that can store a three-digit integer

active: a character field that can hold a value of Y or N

my code for oracle is

For the first table is for acctmanager

```
alter table ACCTMANAGER
add ( Comm_id number(2) default 10,
      Ben_id number(2) 
);
```

the reason why i chose number is because it wants a max value of 99

second table

```
create table COMMRATE
( Comm_id number(2) default 10,
  Comm_rank varchar2(15),
  Rate number(0,2) 
);
```

I think that's right, but the problem i have is for the comm_rank because i can choose rather varchar2 or char, but i prefer varchar2

the third table for benefits

```
create table BENEFITS 
( Ben_id number(2),
  Ben_plan char(1),
  Ben_provider number(3),
  Active varchar2(1)
);
```

the last column for active, i choose varchar2, but i think its better to choose char because its just one character that can hold a value of Y or N. Or maybe i should pick char?

Comment: If this is just Oracle, then that should be the only tag here.

Comment: Gosh which DBMS are you using? You have tagged of them and they are NOT the same. However, in all 3 that you have tagged you should drop the idea of using Y or N. Change this to a bit datatype and name the column IsActive. No matter how you slice it though this question is both too broad and entirely opinion based. As such it is off topic for at least two reasons.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference in performance or storage requirements between `varchar` or `char`. I personally prefer a `number(1)` (with a check constraint) as a poor man's workaround to the missing `boolean` data type in Oracle (I try to avoid localized values like Y or N)

Comment: `comm_id` should be PK (primary key) in `commrate` and FK (foreign key) in `acctmanager`, referencing `commrate`. Similar with `ben_rate`. Then, if you have requirements like the numbers should be integers and non-negative, that should be enforced in `commrate` and `benefits`. The column `active` should have a check constraint to force the value to be either `Y` or `N` (or to be either 0 or 1), regardless of what choice you make. You also need to decide if it should have a NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: Also, it makes sense for `comm_id` to have a default value in `acctmanager`, but it doesn't make sense for it to have a default value in `commrate`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - That is true for a very special case (with `char(1)` as the alternative), but **not** in general. A `varchar2` value will use up just enough space to store a string, even if it is declared with a much larger limit. On the other hand, `char(15)` will always allocate - and actually USE, by right-padding with spaces - exactly 15 characters, even if the actual input was only 1 character.

Comment: @mathguy: You are right I should have added that

Answer (score 0):

To provide context, this question comes from the text, *Oracle 12c: SQL* by Joan Casteel.

The question is from chapter 3 and did not cover the concept of constraints yet. Constraints are covered in chapter 4.

For the second table, I got:

```
CREATE TABLE commrate
( comm_id NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 10,
  comm_rank VARCHAR2(15),
  rate NUMBER(2,2) );
```

The only difference was the change from 0 to 2 in "rate NUMBER(2,2)" because with the syntax NUMBER(p,s)...p indicates the total number of digits to the left AND right of the decimal position.

.01 to .99 have 2 digits to the right of the decimal.

I think...